# How to run two or more apps in localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting started with docker and docker-compose. I have the tutorials and I use `docker-compose.yml` file to run one of my sites in my local machine.

I can see my site running by going to http://localhost

My problem now is trying to run more than one site. If one of my sites is running and I try to run another site using `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "exampleCOM_default" with driver "bridge"
Creating exampleCOMphp-fpm ...
Creating exampleCOMmariadb ... error

ERROR: for exampleCOMmariadb  Cannot start service db: driver failed     programming external connectivity on endpoint exampleCOMmariadb     (999572f33113c9fce034b4ed72aaCreating exampleCOMphp-fpm ... done
```

eady allocated
    Creating exampleCOMnginx   ... error

```
ERROR: for exampleCOMnginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint exampleCOMnginx (9dc04f8b06825d7ff535afb1101933be7435c68f4350f845c756fc93e1a0322c): Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint exampleCOMmariadb (999572f33113c9fce034b4ed72aa072708f6f477eb2af8ad614c0126ca457b64): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint exampleCOMnginx (9dc04f8b06825d7ff535afb1101933be7435c68f4350f845c756fc93e1a0322c): Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated
```

Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

This is my docker-compose file. I am using LEMP stack (PHP, NGINX, MARIADB)

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
      container_name: ${SITE_NAME}_mariadb
      build:
        context: ./mariadb
      volumes:
          - ./mariadb/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
          - ./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./logs/mariadb:/var/log/mysql
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
          MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      ports:
          - '${MYSQL_PORT:-3306}:3306'
      command:
          'mysqld --innodb-flush-method=fsync'
      networks:
        - default
      restart: always
    nginx:
      container_name: ${SITE_NAME}_nginx
      build:
        context: ./nginx
        args:
          - 'php-fpm'
          - '9000'
      volumes:
        - ${APP_PATH}:/var/www/app
        - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      depends_on:
        - php-fpm
      networks:
        - default
      restart: always
    php-fpm:
      container_name: ${SITE_NAME}_php-fpm
      build:
          context: ./php7-fpm
          args:
              TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
      volumes:
          - ${APP_PATH}:/var/www/app
          - ./php7-fpm/config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      environment:
          DB_HOST: db
          DB_PORT: 3306
          DB_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
          DB_USERNAME: ${MYSQL_USER}
          DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      networks:
        - default
      restart: always
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

The host port you have mapped to is preventing you from starting another instance of the service even though the docker-compose creates a private network.

You can solve this problem by using random host ports assigned by docker-compose.

The ports entry in docker-compose is

```
ports
 host_port:container_port
```

If you specify only the container port host port is randomly assigned. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)

Comment: Thanks. I have no to prune the system, modify the compose file and redo everything. But before I do, I want to ask. If I have ten sites, how do I make sure each have different port so they won't conflict eachother. Do I give them a different port like 3000, 3001, 3002 ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the host_port values in ranges.

In below example, i've run the nginx containers and started multiple nginx containers that are automatically exposed to host ports based on the range values [30000-30005].

```
 Command: 

        docker run -p 30000-30005:80 --name nginx1 -d nginx

 Output:

 9083d5fc97e0   nginx ... Up 2 seconds    0.0.0.0:30001->80/tcp   nginx1
 f2f9de1efd8c   nginx ... Up 24 seconds   0.0.0.0:30000->80/tcp   nginx
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about for nginx? I did  `ports:
          - '3300:3306'` for both sites but nginx is still `80:80` in both, won't this cause conflict?

Comment: The container/target port won't create conflicts. We should consider this only on host port.

Comment: it doesn't work bro. the mariadb port no longer gives me an error, but nginx throws an error when i start a second app because port 80 is already taken

Comment: Did you keep your ports section like this.? Also, provide your docker ps command output.

Comment: ports:
        - "30000-30005:80"
        - "30010-30015:443"